# How to define java enum with properties in swagger yaml file?

Tags: java, enums, swagger

I'm having a enum in java like

```
public enum Numbers{

        FIRST("FIRST",1),
        SECOND("SECOND",2);
}
```

and I want to generate java code from swagger `.yaml` file like this

```
properties:
  numbers:
    type: string
    description: status of this order
    enum:
      - FIRST
      - SECOND
```

My question is how can I write the `yaml` file to generate an enum like above one?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported yet.